# How to open an external database in mysql on windows

Tags: mysql

So i want to open http://www.seanlahman.com/baseball-archive/statistics/           the above sql table of baseball statistics . I have tried everything I could . I followed all the instructions online about how to open from control panel , mysql workbench , sqlyog . Please tell me an easier way to open this thing. I am a beginner in mysql and I have been trying to open this since 2 days now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to deploy this database.

Downloaded the file *2016 – SQL version – Updated February 26, 2017*.
And run the script using Opened Execute Large Script Wizard in [dbForge Studio for MySQL](https://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/). This operation took several minutes, with no errors.

Studio [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7Wwh.png)